# Shelosha Asar Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The *Tur OC* 101](http://www.sefaria.org/Arbaah_Turim.1.101) discusses how much of the *sh'mone esre* (*amida*) one needs to have concentration on while saying. Amid that, he writes:

> The rabbi, Rabbi Eliezer, wrote that a person should accustom himself that he has concentration, at least, for the closure of each benediction. For they have, [all told,] one hundred thirteen words, just as there are [one hundred thirteen words] in [the prayer of *Chana*](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.2.1-10) and one hundred thirteen times "*lev*" [="heart"] in *Chumash*, to indicate that one needs to have concentration of the heart for them.

---

<sub>This answer previously had less info in it and cited a later source. Many thanks to [Y ez](/users/4794/y-ez) for pointing me to the *Tur*.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Chanoch lived for 300 years after he begat Mesushelach.  Mesushelach was 187 when he begat Lemech.  So, when Chanoch was "no longer", Lemech was...113!

Answer (score 3):

113 is the number of the final *daf* in *Sanhedrin*.